Can Bazel autogenerate headers from custom file types?
I have 100+ files with .idl extension and I would like to use these to generate C and C++ headers. The IDL files are considered sources and the auto-generated headers are not checked in to the repo.
Is there a way in Bazel to glob all files with .idl extension in a directory and generate corresponding headers?
The unrolled shell commands would look something like:
custom_tool ABC.idl -o out/ABC.h
custom_tool DEF.idl -o out/DEF.h
custom_tool ABC.idl -o out/ABC.hpp --cpp
custom_tool DEF.idl -o out/DEF.hpp --cpp
custom_tool ABC.idl -o out/ABC_skel.h --skel
custom_tool DEF.idl -o out/DEF_skel.h --skel
custom_tool ABC.idl -o out/ABC_skel.hpp --cpp --skel
custom_tool DEF.idl -o out/DEF_skel.hpp --cpp --skel
...

I was hoping to use genrule in an Android.bp file but I would be OK with a separate .bzl file to help with the custom commands.
I'm stuck on creating the outs list/filegroup which resembles the globed srcs filegroup of IDLs.

Yes, Bazel can definitely do what you're asking, but I'm not sure about soong or .bp files and I'm honestly not sure I want to pull in the entire AOSP just to check. Assuming soong can rely on a .bzl macro, then you could write a macro like the following:
idl_helper.bzl
# I just call touch, but you can call whatever your CLI tool is
def chained_generator(**kwargs):
  file_rules=[]
  for src in kwargs["srcs"]:
    file_name = src.split(".")[0]

    h_file = file_name + ".h"
    h_rule = file_name + "__h"
    file_rules.append(":" + h_rule)
    native.genrule(
      name=h_rule,
      srcs = [src],
      outs=[h_file],
      cmd="touch $(@)",
    )

    hpp_file = file_name + ".hpp"
    hpp_rule = file_name + "__hpp"
    file_rules.append(":" + hpp_rule)
    native.genrule(
      name=hpp_rule,
      srcs = [src],
      outs=[hpp_file],
      cmd="touch $(@)",
    )

    skel_h_file = file_name + "_skel.h"
    skel_h_rule = file_name + "__skel_h"
    file_rules.append(":" + skel_h_rule)
    native.genrule(
      name=skel_h_rule,
      srcs = [src],
      outs=[skel_h_file],
      cmd="touch $(@)",
    )

    skel_hpp_file = file_name + "_skel.hpp"
    skel_hpp_rule = file_name + "__skel_hpp"
    file_rules.append(":" + skel_hpp_rule)
    native.genrule(
      name=skel_hpp_rule,
      srcs = [src],
      outs=[skel_hpp_file],
      cmd="touch $(@)",
    )

  native.filegroup(
    name=kwargs["name"],
    srcs=file_rules,
  )

BUILD.bazel or hopefully a .bp file
chained_generator(
    name="generate_headers",
    srcs = glob(["**/*.idl"])
)

Run as single genrule
Soong or .bp files seem a lot more limited. But if this were a bazel build file, you could get everything to run in a single for loop using list comprehension, but this solution also isn't very scalable because it would run for all .idl files even if only one .idl file changed. This probably wouldn't work in a .bp file and a macro would be better regardless.
IDL_FILES=glob(
    include=["*.txt"]
)
FILES_OUT_H = [x.split(".")[0] + ".h" for x in IDL_FILES]
FILES_OUT_HPP = [x.split(".")[0] + ".hpp" for x in IDL_FILES]
FILES_OUT_SKEL_H = [x.split(".")[0] + "_skel.h" for x in IDL_FILES]
FILES_OUT_SKEL_HPP = [x.split(".")[0] + "_skel.hpp" for x in IDL_FILES]

genrule(
    name="test",
    srcs=IDL_FILES,
    outs=FILES_OUT_H + 
    FILES_OUT_HPP +
    FILES_OUT_SKEL_H +
    FILES_OUT_SKEL_HPP,
    cmd="""
        echo $(OUTS)
        for i in "$(OUTS)"
        do
            touch $$i
        done
    """,
)

